# i am using two gridview in asp.net and i canot get which row is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

in them if I use same code for a page having 1 `gridview` then its ok and code is working fine but when I am using it in another page where there is two gridview then code is not working I got stuck through googling please help me my code is:

```
<div id="id1" style="overflow:scroll; height:155px; float:left; width:40%; " >
                    <asp:GridView ID="dgvclass" runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        Width="100%"
                        DataKeyNames="ClassName"
                        EmptyDataText="No record found !!"

                        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="gvEmpty" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" Width="40px" /> </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Class Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="ClassName" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="ClassID" />

                        </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    </div>

                <div id="id2" style="overflow:scroll; height:155px; float:right; width:40%; margin-top:-16%; " >
                    <asp:GridView ID="dgvcatogory" runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        Width="100%"
                        DataKeyNames="CategoryName"
                        EmptyDataText="No record found !!"

                        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="gvEmpty" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow1" runat="server" /> </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="CategoryName" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category ID" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataField="CategoryID" />

                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    </div>
```

and my c# code is:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in dgvclass.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        CheckBox chkrow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
                        if (chkrow.Checked)
                        {
                            foreach (GridViewRow row1 in dgvcatogory.Rows)
                            {
                                if (row1.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                                {
                                    CheckBox chkrow1 = (row1.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow1") as CheckBox);

                                    if (chkrow1.Checked)
                                    {
//some condition
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

it is always showing the `chkRow` value as false, if I set the value true in `gridview` then it always show it as true

Comment: Show your code of gridview binding ?

Comment: For Classstring sqlclass = "select ClassName,ClassID from [Class]";
        DataSet dsclass = new DataSet();
        dsclass = queries.getDetails(sqlclass);
        if (dsclass.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dsclass.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ClassName"].ToString() != "")
            {
                dgvclass.DataSource = dsclass.Tables[0];
                dgvclass.DataBind();
            }
        }

Comment: i gave same answer before druga why not accepr my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as per the discussion in the `comments` section, `!IsPostBack` is what causing the problem.

So the obvious solution is

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    //Bind the gridviews
}
```

Comment: @RahulKumarChoudhary What's the problem are you facing, it's not clear for me.

Comment: when i am pressing save button the gridview checkbox  chkrow.Checked or chkrow1.Checked always show "false" even if it checked thats my problem i want to save one rows which is checked not the whole grid

Comment: @RahulKumarChoudhary Can you post your `Page_Load` method. I suspect you are binding the `gridviews` on every `postback`. This could be one of the reasons for not showing expected result

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding the `gridview` on `Page_Load` make sure you have set `if(!IsPostBack)`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
dgvclass.DataSource = dsclass.Tables[0]; 
dgvclass.DataBind();
}
```